# A entity with active record, is a object or a component?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, architecture

A entity with active record is a object or a component?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'entity' and 'component'. What's at stake in the distinction you're drawing?

Comment: ops, i corrects the mistake..thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jeff Sternals comment on your question; but the short answer is probably "yes" - in that an entity with an active record would be an object - it won't be a component.

In my experience: a component is usually a specific sub-system or part of a solution that has a clearly defined interface and which can be re-used in multiple solutions.

I'd also suggest that a component isn't something that would typically be used as a stand-alone system; a component is something like an engine or chassis, unlike a car or truck which would be a complete "system".

So a component is an architecture concept - entities and objects are concepts that exist more at the code / design level.

Also `Entity` can have different meanings depending on the context.